# Glossaries entry with \dot not working

Tags: glossaries

The entry 'dota' is not working correctly when the default math font is used and it is called with `\gls{dota}`. Dose anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{dota}{
name={\ensuremath{\dot{a}}},
description={something}
}
\newglossaryentry{veca}{ 
name={\ensuremath{\vec{a}}},
description={somthing else}
}

%\usepackage{cmbright} % with another math font it would work

\begin{document}
%   \gls{dota} % if this line is activated the code dose not compile but no error appears
    \gls{veca}
    \ensuremath{\dot{a}} %just the command works
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
name={\ensuremath{\protect\dot{a}}},
```

and it will work.